# Is it possible to incorporate ScoreNinja with Android mode Processing Discourse?

Tags: android, ide, processing, scoreninja

I'm a bit stuck on incorporating ScoreNinja with Processing Discourse as my knowledge doesn't quite stretch far enough.  The API for ScoreNinja is quite shallow so I'm finding it hard to figure out what to do with it.  The system looks really good but its hard to find info on it.

Is anyone up for taking the challenge of getting ScoreNinja to work with Android mode for processing discourse, or at least pointing me in the right direction for getting a global score table working for it?

The site for processing is http://www.processing.org

You can switch to Android mode once installed using the tab on the top right of the IDE.